# shebang is ignored by rosrun

Tags: rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a specific python interpreter to run a ros node written by python. For example, I created a package named tmp, and there is a python code named tmp_new.py in catkin_ws/src/tmp/scripts. The content of tmp_new.py is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

I have edited CMakeLists.txt so that the python executable file can be found:

> catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
> scripts/tmp_new.py
> DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
> )

After then, I run *catkin_make* to build the package, *source devel/setup.bash* to set the environment, and *rosrun tmp tmp_new.py* to execute the toy python file.

However, the shebang is completely ignored, and the output is **/usr/bin/python3**.

To rule out the possibility that my shebang is incorrect, I go into catkin_ws/src/tmp/scripts and run *./tmp_new.py* and the shebang is recognized and the output of the program is **/usr/bin/python2**, which conforms to my expectation.

**I am quite confused why this happened? It seems the shebang is completely ignored by rosrun.** I also tried to write a launch file, and the behavior is the same as rosrun.

(Some more information: The above is just a toy example which explains the problem I encountered easily. My final goal is to ask ros to execute a python program with a specific virtualenv environment. For example, I created a virtual environment with *virtualenv venv*, and I set the shebang of the python program to *#!/home/xxxx/catkin_ws/venv/bin/python*. Rosrun always calls */usr/bin/python3* instead of the virtual environment.)

Environment:

- ROS version: Noetic 1.15.11
- Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64, kernel 5.10.9-051009-generic
- My default python interpreter is /usr/bin/python3
- env | grep ROS

> ROS_VERSION=1
> ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/xxxx/catkin_ws_jetson/src:/home/xxxx/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/noetic/share
> ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/xxxx/catkin_ws_jetson/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/xxxx/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
> ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
> ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros
> ROS_DISTRO=noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382839/shebang-is-ignored-by-rosrun/) by [zptang](https://answers.ros.org/users/78215/zptang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2021-07-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zptang](https://answers.ros.org/users/78215/zptang/) on 2021-07-20**:
Well, I found a solution by myself.
If I don't edit the CMakeLists.txt file of the packge as I said in the question, i.e.

```
# catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS scripts/tmp_new.py DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION} )
```

and *delete the build and devel folders*, and run *catkin_make* again.

*rosrun tmp tmp_new.py* will use the shebang and call the python2 interpreter.

However, **I still don't know why this happen? Anybody can explain this?** Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `catkin_install_python` directive automatically [rewrites the shebang](http://docs.ros.org/en/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html) on your file to match the Python version specified by the ROS version (since you are on Noetic, ROS_PYTHON_VERSION is set to 3).

If you really want to keep the shebang setup for Python 2, you would want to use a plain old `install` directive in CMake would would not do the extra shebang rewrite.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2021-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zptang](https://answers.ros.org/users/78215/zptang/) on 2021-07-27**:
Thanks for your answer!

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2021-09-27**:
Thanks, please click the checkmark next to the answer to accept it so this gets marked as answered.

**Comment by [zptang](https://answers.ros.org/users/78215/zptang/) on 2021-09-27**:
Done!!!!!!